# JSON data modeling: users who have access to projects

Tags: json, model, data-modeling

When structuring our data model *(JSON in a document database)*, we have `users` which are part of a `project`. I.E. a project has many users and a user can be part of many projects.

Does it make sense to store each project a user has access to in the user:

```
{
   "id": "u1"
   "name": "John Doe",
   "email": "john.doe@domain.com",
   "projects": [
       "p1",
       "p2",
       "p3"
   ]
}
```

Or instead store the users in the projects themselve:

```
{
    "id": "p1"
    "name": "Project A",
    "users": [
        "u1"
    ]
}

{
    "id": "p2"
    "name": "Project B",
    "users": [
        "u1"
    ]
}

{
    "id": "p3"
    "name": "Project C",
    "users": [
        "u1"
    ]
}
```

We anticipate needing to select all projects for a given user as well as selecting all users for a given project.

Answer (score 0):

According to document of Mongo database (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents), two ways above is fine. 
I think the business will make decision that which data model should be chosen, for e.g, if there were only one or two projects but many users and you only need to show list of projects of users, the first way is better.
P/S: If you use Mongo, please consider to use mongoose which helps to retrieve data easily.